# Optimize query which uses remote tables

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have such query:

```
select DISTINCT
    cn.ID                    
    cn.name                  
    child.ID             
    child2.ID             
    child3.ID             
    child.status        
    child2.status      
    child3.status        
from People cn
left join relation@db_link rel
  on rel.PARENT_ID = cn.ID
left join People child
  on child.ID = rel.CHILD_ID
left join relation@db_link rel2
  on rel2.PARENT_ID = child.ID
left join People child2
  on child2.ID = rel2.CHILD_ID
left join relation@db_link rel3
  on rel3.PARENT_ID = child2.ID
left join People child3
  on child3.ID = rel3.CHILD_ID
where
  cn.name is not null and
  child.status in ( 'Live', 'Awaiting Install' )
```

The problem is that I have relations between people in remote table. Such query runs too long. I tried to avoid this by joining the remote tables together in a subquery. And the same for the local tables - Cost of query increased threefold.
I cannot create materialized view or refresh table in my local database. This data must be live.
Interesting is fact that if I use local relations cost of query is higher but query runs few seconds.

Do you have any idea how i can speed it up?

Comment: First things first. Post the execution plan. There may be a bottleneck you are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You could be having problems for several reasons.

1. How many rows are in Live or Waiting Install status? Are those rare statuses? If so, you'll want nested loops + index access to all tables.  If they are common statuses, you are asking for a whole lot of data, and you'd be better off with full table scans and hash joins. Look at your execution plan and determine whether it is using the right approach. It should be starting with child (people). (By the way, that filter in your WHERE clause effectively makes your first two left joins become inner joins. You might as well change them to inner joins to make it clearer.)
2. If those status are rare and so the number of rows you expect relatively small, it is okay to do nested loops over the dblink. But it drives the time way up if it's doing nested loops over dblinks and the volume (# of loops) is relatively high. This may push you toward hash joins instead.
3. If you end up deciding that hash joins are better, which is larger, people or relation? If the remote table is excessively larger than the local, you want the driving site to be the remote so the smaller local table gets pushed over the link. You can do that with the /*+ driving_site */ hint. If however this is part of a DML (insert,update,delete,merge,CTAS), it won't honor the driving site hint. A workaround in that case is that you can create a view on the remote database with a link to the local database for people and just query the view from the local database, allow it to use the loopback link to get people.
4. You are going three levels deep, to great-grandchildren. Think about how many rows that will pull as you're thinking through this.

Comment: Table relation is much bigger than people so i decided to use hint driving_site. It increased cost but query is much faster, weird..

Comment: That's great to hear, it's not always that easy. A word about cost: ignore it. Oracle will always use the lowest cost plan. If it makes a mistake and does something dumb, it's because its cost calculation is incorrect. Therefore by definition, it should be ignored, it's wrong.